# Create dataframe with arraytype column in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to create a new dataframe with `ArrayType()` column, I tried with and without defining schema but couldn't get the desired result. My code below with schema

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
l = [[1,2,3],[3,2,4],[6,8,9]]
schema = StructType([
  StructField("data", ArrayType(IntegerType()), True)
])
df = spark.createDataFrame(l,schema)
df.show(truncate = False)
```

This gives error:

> ValueError: Length of object (3) does not match with length of fields
> (1)

Desired output:

```
+---------+
|data     |
+---------+
|[1,2,3]  |
|[3,2,4]  |
|[6,8,9]  |
+---------+
```

**Edit:**

I found a strange thing(atleast for me):

if we use the following code, it gives the expected result:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
data = [
    ('person', ['john', 'sam', 'jane']),
    ('pet', ['whiskers', 'rover', 'fido'])
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["type", "names"])
df.show(truncate=False)
```

This gives the following expected output:

```
+------+-----------------------+
|type  |names                  |
+------+-----------------------+
|person|[john, sam, jane]      |
|pet   |[whiskers, rover, fido]|
+------+-----------------------+
```

But if we remove the first column, then it gives unexpected result.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
data = [
    (['john', 'sam', 'jane']),
    (['whiskers', 'rover', 'fido'])
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["names"])
df.show(truncate=False)
```

This gives the following output:

```
+--------+-----+----+
|names   |_2   |_3  |
+--------+-----+----+
|john    |sam  |jane|
|whiskers|rover|fido|
+--------+-----+----+
```

Comment: to create a tuple with a single element, add a coma at the end. `(['john', 'sam', 'jane'],)` The coma makes the tuple, not the parenthesis. `1,` is a tuple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you already have the answer to your question. Another solution is:

```py
>>> l = [([1,2,3],), ([3,2,4],),([6,8,9],)]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ['data'])
>>> df.show()

+---------+
|     data|
+---------+
|[1, 2, 3]|
|[3, 2, 4]|
|[6, 8, 9]|
+---------+
```

or

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import array

>>> l = [[1,2,3],[3,2,4],[6,8,9]]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(l)
>>> df = df.withColumn('data',array(df.columns))
>>> df = df.select('data')
>>> df.show()
+---------+
|     data|
+---------+
|[1, 2, 3]|
|[3, 2, 4]|
|[6, 8, 9]|
+---------+
```

Regarding the strange thing, it is not that strange but you need to keep in mind that the tuple with a single value is the single value itself

```py
>>> (['john', 'sam', 'jane'])
['john', 'sam', 'jane']

>>> type((['john', 'sam', 'jane']))
<class 'list'>
```

so the `createDataFrame` sees a list not the tuple.

Comment: So, `createDataframe` takes tuple for each row and a tuple is denoted by an end `,` . Did I got it right?

Comment: Yes, according to the documentation the comma is one way to construct a tuple:
https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple